# When the dispose() method should be executed?

Tags: flutter, firebase-admob

When the dispose() method should be executed?

For instance, there are two widgets:

- Statefull Widget 1
- Widget 2

The widget 1 has the dispose() method, because this widget intialize admob add, so we should implement there dispose with

```
_bannerAd?.dispose();
```

Now, let's imagine a situation. I go from W1 to W2 and then back to W1.
Should not the dispose() has to be executed? I have modeled such navigation and the dispose() was not execured.

Then I press `back` button on emulator (to return to the W2) and now the dispose was executed(!), why it was executed in this case and was not when we made `navigator push` the widget 2?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because, `.pop()` will remove the route from stack where `.push()` will not, removing from stack essentially means disposing.
(pop happens when you come back W2)

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `_bannerAd?.dispose();` part inside of the `dispose` callback of the statefullWidget:

```
/* inside the statefullWidget class */
@override
dispose(){
  super.dispose();
  _bannerAd?.dispose();
}
```

Flutter will take care of the rest.

Comment: actually, it has already was there, and it's not about what I asked